# How to set TableModel as DataSource in an empty iReport (NetBeans 7.1)

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports, ireport

This is my first time to create a report using `iReport` plugin in `Netbeans 7.1`. I have all the records that I need (*records were stored in a **TableModel***) and I want it to set as the `datasource` to an empty report.

Here's what I did so far:

> 1.)  I have a **TableModel** from a **ResultSet**. (fields: *StudentID, FullName, SectionName*)

```
        private TableModel ConvertResultSetToTableModel(ResultSet rs)
        {
             TableModel tb;
             ... // codes here
             return tb;
        }
```

> 2.) I added an **EmptyReport** on my project. *The reason why it's empty is because I do not want iReport to connect to my database server.*

[image: Adding Empty Report]

> 3.) This is my sample report (*no elegant design yet*). How can I **bind or fill the fields** of the TableModel (fields: *StudentID, FullName, SectionName*) to the **TextField** of the iReport (***$F{StudentID}, $F{FullName}, $F{SectionName}***)? And how can I also directly set the ***$F{CourseName}*** TextField from a local string variable?

[image: Sample Report]

I hope I made everything clear here. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the answer to your question

Jasper reports provides implementation that makes the task of generating reports from tabular formats simple in Swing 
applications. In this demonstrations, we will be using Jasper reports 3.6.1, Netbeans 6.1 and Ireport 3.6.1.

Try this code

```
    private void generateReports(String name, Map param)
{
        try
        {
                String source = "C:/sabonay/jasperreports/" + name + ".jrxml";
                if (new File(source).exists() == false)
                {
                        xputils.showMessage("Please go to setting and Choose report Source");
                        return;
                }

                JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(source);
                JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, param, new JRTableModelDataSource(tbProducts.getModel()));

                JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("reports Error  " + e.toString());

        }
}
```

[For more Info Visit this link...](http://gilbertadjin.wordpress.com/2009/11/22/tablemodel-as-datasource-in-jasper-reports/)